# WooCommerce Checkout: hide Billing details

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout

[image]

i don't want to take billing information, i want to hide this form input, and want to organize the checkout page, i have tried to

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
unset($fields['billing']['billing_first_name']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
return $fields;
}
```

unset the billing details but this don't hide "Billing details" label, and unable to organize the checkout page, please help, waiting for reply, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields', 100 );

function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields(){
    return [];
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'include_styles' );

function include_styles() {
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
       echo '
            <style>
                .woocommerce-billing-fields h3 {
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
       ';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, Alex Vasilyev, this helps to remove the billing details section but how will i organize the checkout page? as i want to move shipping details to left side and order, payment blocks to right side,